# Legend order in ggpubr

Tags: r, bar-chart, ggpubr

Is there a way to invert the legend order of a barplot in ggpubr?

When the barplot is in the horizontal position the legends follow the order of the groups in the plot...

[image]

But when I rotate the plot, I wish the legend would follow the groups order from top to bottom

[image]

```
ggbarplot(df, x="cat", y="percent", 
                           color = "white", 
                           fill = "cat2",
                           sort.by.groups = TRUE,
                           sort.val = "asc",
                           rotate = TRUE,
                           palette = "nejm",
                           alpha = 0.9,
                           ylab = "Ylab", xlab = "Xlab",
                           legend.title = "Title", legend= "right")
```

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`scale_fill_manual` helps you with this task.

**An example:**

*Data from package's examples:*

```
df <- data.frame(dose=c("D0.5", "D1", "D2"),
                 len=c(4.2, 10, 29.5))
```

*Make the base barplot:*

```
ggbarplot(df, "dose", "len",
          fill = "dose",
          palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"), legend =  "right")
```

[image]

*Now we can rotate plot and change legend:*

```
ggbarplot(df, "dose", "len",
          fill = "dose",
          palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"), orientation = "horiz", legend = "right") + 
          scale_fill_manual(name = "dose", 
                            values = c("D2" = "#00AFBB", "D1"="#E7B800", "D0.5"="#FC4E07"))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work

Comment: @Lala It still works (R 4.1.0).  Where is a problem?